# Converting point into line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, point, sql, polyline-creation

I have a set of points with datatype as `geometry(MultiPoint, 32643)`, I want each point to be converted in short line segments. The purpose of doing this is to use `"split by lines"` tool in QGIS which splits a line layer with another line layer.

The suggestion in one of the answer is as below, but I could not find the geometry by expression tool. Also, I tried to implement the below command in PostgreSQL but it didn't work.

```
Convert your points into short line segments with the geometry by expression tool.
Use an expression like this:

make_line($geometry, translate($geometry, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Better try with **st_makeline**, **st_translate** ...

Comment: Yes, that worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there are 10 features in *'points'* layer accordingly, see image below.

[image: original]

With the following query, it is possible *to convert each point into a short line segment.*

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,
    make_line(p.geometry, translate(p.geometry,1,50))
FROM
    points AS p
```

P.S. Mind the CRS.

The output Virtual Layer will generate short line segments including point's `"id"` where the initial point feature is the starting point of a line segment.

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [SQL functions for coordinate transformations | ST_Translate](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html#p15)