# Transforming points into graduated segments in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, geometry-generator, segment

In QGIS 3.16 I've got a point layer for several sample points in a coastal stretch. The attribute `"EPR0113_er"` indicates the erosion rate recorded at that point and I would like to represent it, not as a point, but as a segment whose length is related to the `"EPR0113_er"` value.

I've been trying different approaches using the Geometry Generator tool, without success. Any ideas about how to build it?

Comment: Can you please give an example/graphic of your desired *"graduated segments"*?

Comment: Maybe this thread can help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324974/converting-point-into-line-using-qgis

Comment: Is there any orientation/direction value in the point layer?

Comment: @Taras I really don't have any preferred design for the segments. They can be simple lines or, as suggested in the answer given below, as wedges.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz There's no direction attribute, only positive or negative values for accretion or erosion rates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use wedge buffer:

```
wedge_buffer($geometry, 120, 10, "rate", 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If there is an azimuth value (ex. `AZIM`) in the layer, you can use this:

```
make_line($geometry, project($geometry, EPR0113_er, radians(AZIM)))
```

otherwise, you can specify any direction value:

```
make_line($geometry, project($geometry, EPR0113_er, radians(100)))
```

[image]